# Firebase function not returning edited index HTML content

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions, facebook-opengraph

I have a Vue app deployed on Firebase Hosting. Until recently we had no need to add dynamic Open Graph tags to it but now we do, and the path we took is a Firebase Function that executes for all the paths when the app should be served.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/spa",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "host"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

You can notice in the `firebase.json` file above that there is a function called `host` that is executed for all paths. And this is working fine, I can see the execution of the function in the console, I also checked the logs and it is modifying the `index.html` file as expected, but at the end it looks like the original `index.html` (which is found under `dist/spa`) file is returned to the user. The code is bellow:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const fs = require('fs');

exports.host = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  let indexHTML = fs.readFileSync('./hosting/index.html').toString();

  console.log('original: ', indexHTML);

  // const userAgent = req.headers['user-agent'].toLowerCase();
  const ogPlaceholder = '<meta name=functions-insert-dynamic-og>';

  // Cache the response for 10 minutes
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=600, s-maxage=1200');
  indexHTML = indexHTML.replace(ogPlaceholder, getOpenGraph());

  console.log('modified: ', indexHTML);

  res.status(200).send(indexHTML);
});

const desc =
  'Desc here';
const imageURL =
  'imageUrlHere';
const title = 'Title Here';

const getOpenGraph = () => {
  return `<meta property="og:title" content="${title}">
          <meta property="og:site_name" content="SiteName">
          <meta property="og:url" content="URL">
          <meta property="og:description" content="${desc}">
          <meta property="og:type" content="website">
          <meta property="og:image" content="${imageURL}">`;
};
```

During our build process the Vue template index file is copied over to `function/hosting`. That file is read using `fs` and a placeholder string is replaced with the appropriate Open Graph tags. But the source that is served is still the original one...

Answer (score 1):

You might try adding a second root folder to your project so that it no longer builds your single root folder into lib/ and instead builds it in the subdirectory. Everything worked again once you modified firebase.json with the new URL to index.js.

Before executing Firebase deploy, you can try running `npm run build` in your functions folder to confirm that your source code is compiled.

If you want to look at the real logs to figure out what's wrong, use the command `firebase functions:log`. This command will display the exact problem, which could be as simple as a missing firebase.json.

Another suggestion would be to delete firebase.json and start over.

Comment: The issue was that my main `index.html` was still served from the public folder. I renamed that  to `index_temp.html` during build so it is not the access point. Now the function returns the `index.html `which is edited.